# Tar --absolute-names flag does not work

Tags: backup, tar, directory-structure, compression, archive

I would like to put everything into an archive from a given directory, while also saving the whole dierctory layout, so superior directory names would be required.

I run the following command:

`tar --create --gzip --recursion --file=/home/user/test_backup.tgz --directory=/home/user/opt .`

However this only saves the directory layout from under `opt`.

```
dir1
dir1/file
file1
file2
```

As I understand from the manual, I should use `--absolute-names` or `-P`, but neither of them works when I add them to the command above.

`tar --absolute-names --create --gzip --recursion --file=/home/user/test_backup.tgz --directory=/home/user/opt .`

What could be the problem?

The desired directory layout in the archive should be:

```
/home/user/opt/dir1
/home/user/opt/dir1/file
/home/user/opt/file1
/home/user/opt/file2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `--directory FOO .` you're telling `tar` to change to the FOO directory and start archiving from there.

If you want full path names then you should specify them as the pattern.

eg

```
tar -czf /home/user/test_backup.tgz /home/user/opt
```

However this will strip off the leading `/` character, so you need to tell `tar` to not do that:

```
tar --absolute-names -czf /home/user/test_backup.tgz /home/user/opt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tar -P -cvzf archive.tgz /path/to/dir
```

This will create an archive containing the contents of `/path/to/dir` with a complete path starting with `/path/to/dir`.

You will also have to use `-P` when extracting the files from the archive if you want the leading `/` in the paths to be preserved.